# What is a voltage divider and how does it works?

Tags: voltage-divider

Ok so this is a voltage divider shown in my text-book

[image]

There was not much detail about it and from what is given I can't get an idea of what it's purpose is and how it works, can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that the voltage you apply, \$V_{IN}\$ is *divided* so that at the output you have a smaller voltage \$V_{OUT}\$ that depends on the input voltage and the resistors.

First of all let's set our reference voltage at the lower node, the one where only \$R_2\$ is connected.
Analyzing the circuit you can see that there is some current \$I_d\$ flowing in the resistors:

$$I_d=\frac{V_{IN}}{R_1+R_2}$$

All this current flows of course in \$R_2\$ so that:

$$V_{OUT}=I_d\cdot R_2 = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1+R_2}\cdot R_2=V_{IN}\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

Note that \$V_{OUT} \leq V_{IN}\$ holds always, or better holds as long as \$R_1,R_2 > 0\$, that is always the case.

The purposes of the voltage divider are quite a lot, you can use it to polarize other components, i.e. to supply them with the correct working voltage, you can use it to reduce a signal amplitude: the knob volume control is based on a divider. You can use it to provide some feedback, the divider itself has some sort of feedback built in. It's one of the most basic circuit you will ever find.

Comment: "you can use it to reduce a signal amplitude", actually this was given in my book and it was little bit confusing it seems like signal was being amplified that's what made to ask the question , thanks for the explanation

Comment: I can only assume you have not been shown the general rule used in most circuit designs that input is on the left and output is on the right. This is the only way I could think it was amplifying the signal when in fact it attenuates the signal (even that logic does not make consistent sense) So any signal flows from left to right of the page. There are often instances where a signal does go right to left (these are feedback signals). Can you explain what caused you to think this was amplifying? (I often have to teach this sort of concept, it would help me understand this from a starters POV)

Answer (score 3):

Since an answer has already been accepted, I'll just add that you the dual of the voltage divider is the *current* divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNJYKb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Instead of resistors in series with a voltage source where the voltage divides proportionally across the resistors, we have *conductances* in *parallel* with a *current source* where the *current* divides proportionally *through* the conductances.

The nice thing about duals is that the dual of a valid formula is a valid formula.

For example, for voltage division, we have

$$V_{R2} = V_{in}\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

The dual of this formula is

$$I_{G2} = I_{in}\frac{G_2}{G_1 + G_2}$$

which indeed gives the correct result for the current through G2.

Now, given that \$G = \frac{1}{R}\$, we can write this formula in terms of resistance

$$I_{G2} = I_{in}\frac{\frac{1}{R_2}}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}} = I_{in}\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

which is the more familiar formula for current division.

Comment: Alfred, feel free to edit my answer and add your infos.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the voltage divider as more of a tool for circuit analysis, rather than a circuit that provides a specific function.

When you are trying to figure out what a circuit does, and you see two resistors in series, knowing the voltage divider rule gives you a simple formula to predict what the voltage will be at the middle node, given that you know the voltages at the end nodes.

That said, there are cases where voltage dividers are used as functional elements. For example when a potentiometer is used to control some circuit parameter, or when setting up the bias point of a MOSFET gate in a common source amplifier.